# What is the order of each element in $\mathbb{Z_4}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I understand that for each $x \in \mathbb{Z_4}$ we're trying to find the smallest $k$ such that $x^k \equiv 1 \mod 4$. So we have $x = 0$ to begin with, but $0^n \mod 4$ for any positive integer $n$ will never equal $1.$ Similarly $2^n \mod 4$ will always be $0$ for positive $n$.

Am I thinking about the order of the elements incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are slightly confused: The order of an element $x$ of any group $G$ is the smallest $k$ such that $x^k=e$, where $e$ is the identity element.

In this case, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is a group under addition, and so the identity element is $0$, not $1$.

Hope this clears things up!

Comment: How do you determine the identity element in a group?

Comment: In general, we usually just denote it as "$e$".  For specific groups, it is clear based on how the group has been defined. For example, if the group is the additive group of integers mod $n$, then going back to the properties of modular arithmetic, it becomes clear that $0 + x = x$ for any residue class $x$, and so the residue class of $0$ must be our identity. Another example would be the multiplicative group of integers mod $n$: $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$. Again, given the properties of modular arithmetic, it is clear that $1 \cdot x = x$ for any $x$, and so $1$ is the identity element.

Comment: Why is it the case, then, that if a group $G$ has an element of order $|G|$, then that group is necessarily cyclic?

Comment: For most other groups, symmetry groups for instance, we literally call it "the identity element", since trivially, the identity is a permutation.

Comment: @JoelB, Suppose $x$ has order $|G|$.  Then $x^n \neq x^m$ for any $n,m < |G|$.  Otherwise, we'd have $x^{n-m} = e$, and that contradicts the fact that the order of $x$ is $|G|$.  Thus, for all $k < |G|$, $x^k$ is a unique element.  That's not particularly related to what you're asking here, though.

Comment: I know, sorry. They are related concepts I'm having difficulty grasping. Another is: if ord($G$) $=4$ and $G$ is not cyclic, then every non-identity element has order $2$.

Comment: Have you covered Lagrange's theorem yet?  I think you'd get the best feedback if you either edited your question or created more than one question.  It's often difficult to adequately clear things up in the comments, and it's also more difficult for people (most of whom are much more experienced than I am) to participate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess, the *additive order* was intended here, as $\Bbb Z_4$ is made a group only by addition.

You are right that $0$ and $2$ have no multiplicative orders. Nota bene, the multiplicative group (of invertible elements) of $\Bbb Z_4$ consists only of $1$ and $3(=-1)$.